# Flask shutdown after working 10-15 sec

Tags: python, flask, bots, messenger

I am developing a python messenger Bot using a wrapper from [pymessenger](https://github.com/davidchua/pymessenger). It works locally but in production it breaks.Like in every sec there are 15-20 req. I am using Pm2 to restart the process when shutdown/close. When i start the app it run for 10-20 sec, works as expected but suddenly show that error and restart. i would really appreciate if anybody can help me.

Here is the code:

```
# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import os
import emoji
from flask import Flask, request
from pymessenger.bot import Bot    
app = Flask(__name__)

bot = Bot(ACCESS_TOKEN)


@app.route("/webhook", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == VERIFY_TOKEN:
            return request.args.get("hub.challenge")
        else:
            return 'Invalid verification token'
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            output = request.get_json()
            for event in output['entry']:
                if event.get("messaging"):
                    messaging = event['messaging']
                    for x in messaging:
                        if x.get('message'):
                            recipient_id = x['sender']['id']
                            if x['message'].get('text'):
                                message = emoji.demojize(x['message']['text'])


#-----------------------some other code ------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------
                                bot.send_text_message(
                                    recipient_id, "replay")
                            if x['message'].get('attachments'):
                                bot.send_text_message(
                                    recipient_id, "No result!!")
                        else:
                            pass
                return "Success"
        return "Success"
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
    except ValueError:
        print "Could not convert data to an integer."
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(port=5000, debug=False)
```

*I am not a python developer,just using it for a library i can't find in other platform for messenger Bot.*

**Here is Error log:**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
   self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
     self.finish()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
     self.wfile.close()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close
     self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
 socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: https://vsupalov.com/flask-web-server-in-production/

Comment: i am using nginx in front of the server, like proxy server. Any solution with nginx?

Comment: @error404: yes, deploy to a WSGI server that you put behind NGINX.

Comment: Take the `print`s out and use the `logging` package. Debugging will be considerably easier.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the built-in server that comes with Flask, in production. Don't do that, it was only ever designed as a convenience to make developing easy. It can't handle real-life production edgecases.

What's happening is that the remote client the server was sending a response to, has closed the connection early. This happens from time to time, is not quite how it is supposed to work, but that's the internet for you. This is not something you need to care about when developing your app, so the built-in server doesn't handle this edgecase.

Instead, you need to deploy Flask on a *production-quality WSGI server*. That can be Apache with `mod_wsgi`, or Gunicorn, or uWSGI, or any other such server. See the [*Deploying* chapter of the Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) with Flask to manage the WSGI requests. Here are the small scripts which can help you start and stop Flask Server running with Gunicorn. Flask's built-in server is not made to be used in production. It crashes with time. Therefore look into the Gunicorn:

**Start Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
stat=0
COUNTER=0
swait()
{
        echo -ne "Waiting for service to start"
                until [[ $stat -ge 1 ]]
                do
        stat=$(netstat -lnt | awk '$4 ~ /:5001$/' |wc -l)
                        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
                        if [ $COUNTER == 5 ] ; then
                                echo -e '\nError-Service start failed'
                                exit;
                         fi
                        echo -ne "."
                        sleep 2 
                    done
}
service_start()
{
        echo "Starting Service"

        /<project_path>/venv/bin/gunicorn --reload -b 0.0.0.0:5001 api:app --access-logfile=/var/log/<project_name>.log --error-logfile=/var/log/<project_name>_error.log -D -w 2 --access-logformat='%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" %(L)s' --log-level=info

}
service_start
swait

echo -e "\nService started Successfully"
```

**Stop Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Stopping Service"
stat=1
COUNTER=0

swait()
{
        echo -ne "Waiting for service to stop"
                until [[ $stat -eq 0 ]]
                do
        stat=$(netstat -lnt | awk '$4 ~ /:5001$/' |wc -l)
                        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
                        if [ $COUNTER == 8 ] ; then
                                echo -e '\nService stop failed'
                                exit;
                         fi
                        echo -ne "."
                        sleep 2 
                    done
}

service_stop()
{
        for pid in `ps augx | grep gunicorn | grep -E ':5001' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`;
        do
                echo "Killing PID" $pid
                kill $pid
        done
}

service_stop
swait


echo -e "\nService Stopped Successfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used Waitress with Flask, Flash is basic WSGI service for testing only

> https://github.com/Pylons/waitress